# "if not exist \\ip\SharedDirectory\." in batch file creates delay

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I would like to open a network drive in the explorer. The network drive is hosted on a PC, that is sometimes connected by WLAN and sometimes connected by LAN. Because of that, it has two different IPs.
I don´t know when the PC is connected by one or the other.

Using shortcuts to open the drive has two shortcomings.

1. obviously I have to try both, if the PC is not present at the first
   shortcuts network address.
2. if I open a shortcut to a drive that is not existing (temporary), then the explorer freezes for like 30 seconds.

So I wrote a batch containing this commands:

```
@echo off

echo try LAN

if not exist \\<IPLAN>\Buecherei$\. (goto WLAN)
    explorer \\<IPLAN>\Buecherei$\.
    goto end

:WLAN
echo try WLAN

if not exist \\<IPWLAN\Buecherei$\. (goto end)
    explorer \\<IPWLAN>\Buecherei$\.
    goto end

:end
```

But if the PC is connected by WLAN, and I start the batch file, it also takes quite a long time to start reaching for the WLAN-IP address based folder path. How can I eliminate that delay?

Comment: As it wpuld seem to be taking time timing out looking at the network, why not check the IP range/gateway instead?

Comment: Why not use the hostname instead of the IP?

Comment: It has been two days now with 3 different answers given. Do you still need help with this? If not, can you accept the answer that was most helpful so we know you no longer need help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ping` and `%errorlevel%` to check if a network is available. This way, you can make the checks quick.

Here's how you would make your script. Replace the IP addresses with the actual ones.

```
    @echo off
    
::  -- Lets check which network is available.


    echo try LAN
    
::  -- We'll ping the address with a timeout of 30ms exactly 1 times, but hide the ping to the user
    ping 12.34.56.78 -n 1 -w 30 > nul
    
::  -- Now, lets find out if the destination was reached or not.
::  -- %errorlevel% will return 0 when it was reached, 1 when it timed out.

    if %errorlevel%==0 goto LAN
    
::  -- If we reached here, LAN was not available. Trying WLAN...


    echo try WLAN
    
::  -- We'll ping the address with a timeout of 30ms exactly 1 times, but hide the ping to the user
    ping 87.65.43.21 -n 1 -w 30 > nul
    
::  -- Now, lets find out if the destination was reached or not.
::  -- %errorlevel% will return 0 when it was reached, 1 when it timed out.

    if %errorlevel%==0 goto WLAN
    

::  -- If we reached here, WLAN was not available either. We'll just quit the script.
    goto end
    

:LAN
::  -- open the explorer
    explorer \\12.34.56.78\Buecherei$\.
    goto end
    
:WLAN
::  -- open the explorer
    explorer \\87.65.43.21\Buecherei$\.
    goto end
    
:end
```

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to use the DNS name, and have DHCP server update the DNS name.

Thus instead of `\\<IPLAN>\ or \\<IPWAN>\`

You use \\SERVERNAME\ instead and the network does a DNS lookup gets the correct value and your done.

Comment: This will still fail with a long timeout if neither network is available.